# How to modify ASCII with prime numbers C program

Tags: c

Here's my program that asks a user to enter a line of text and then shows the ASCII code it's associated with, and than after that it modifies the ASCII code by adding plus 1 to i, and it also prints out the new character associated with that new ASCII code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char s[ 70 ]; // define character array of size 70
    size_t i; // loop counter

    // use gets to get text from user
    puts( "Enter a line of text: \a\n" );
    fgets( s, 70, stdin );

    // convert each character to ASCII and output
    puts("\n ASCII code for the characters \n");
    for ( i = 0; s[ i ] != '\0'; ++i )
    {
        printf(" %c:%d",(s[ i ]),(s[ i ]));
    } // end for  Uppercase ASCII

    // convert each character to modified ASCII and output
    puts( "\nThe line modified with progressively higher ASCII:\n" );
    for ( i = 0; s[ i ] != '\0'; ++i )
    {
        printf( "%c", ( s[ i ] + (i+1)) );
    } // end for modified characters

    puts("");
    printf( " \n modified  ASCII code for the entered string \n\n\a");
    for ( i = 0; s[ i ] != '\0'; ++i )
    {
        printf( " %c:%d",(s[ i ] + (i+1)),(s[ i ] +(i+1)));
    } // end for  modified ASCII code
    printf( "\n \t The final value of loop variable 'i' is:%d\n", i);
    puts( "" );
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

I'm having difficulty modifying it so that the ASCII code and characters change by the first seven prime numbers 2,3,5...17 and than after those first 7 prime numbers are up go in reverse 17,13,11,7,...2. So after the first loop say g has ASCII code 103, the modified ASCII code will now be 105 and the new letter will now be i. Can anybody help me out?

Comment: sorry i just edited it, it was a mistake on my part

Comment: Hint: how do you know `s[ i ] + (i+1)` is printable ASCII?

Comment: The %d prints out the letters in ASCII, you just enter a string of characters in and than it translates it from characters %c to ASCII %d.

Comment: The s[ i  ] + (i+1) is the part of the program that modifies the ASCII, i changes after every loop, it becomes one greater ++i so for the first loop it's 0 next loop 1 etc.

Answer (score 1):

Start by declaring an array storing your pattern (primes, in ascending order and then descending order, in such a way that reducing modulo the arrays size will cause a cycle). For example:

```
unsigned int prime[] = { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 13, 11, 7, 5, 3 };
```

Now, rather than adding `(i + 1)` to each character in your loop, you'll want to add `prime[i % (sizeof prime / sizeof *prime)]`. For example:

```
for (i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++)
{
     putchar(s[i] + prime[i % (sizeof prime / sizeof *prime)]);
}
```

P.S. Technically, it's not required to be ASCII. Think of it this way: C and ASCII go together like coffee and cows milk. Most people love it, but occasionally someone will use coconut milk or cream instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback and this answer makes a lot of sense.

Comment: One last question if i wanted to do it for a string of characters that's say 68 characters long, would i have to continually do the pattern or is there a more efficient way?

Comment: You'll understand the answer to that question when you know what the modulo (`%`) operator does... As you can see, this answer uses it.

Comment: nvm it was a mistake on my part

Comment: Oh, well... That happens to the best of us.

Comment: I noticed you put 15 by accident as a prime, i deleted it from the list, but when i run the program the modified ASCII still comes out with 15 added.

Comment: @Jimmy Oops! My bad... I've changed it to 17 in my code. I think you might have an error causing compilation to fail, so you'd be running an old binary...

Comment: nvm i fixed it again haha, thanks for all the help, have a good one

Comment: We are a couple of clumsy coders, aren't we? If this was your favourite answer, care to give it your tick of approval?