# Arrays in C and Prime Numbers

Tags: c, arrays, numbers, variable-assignment

I need help with my programming assignment, I have everything done except for one part! Here is the assignment:

> Problem 1: String Operations and Data Security:  To improve data security in the transmission of data and information, dynamic character coding is being practiced.  The modification of the original characters can be using the first 8 prime members [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17]:  First character enhanced by 1; second character by 2, third by 3,  .. 8th character by 17.   Next 8 characters use the prime numbers in the reverse order 17..1, and decrease the values.   Use a total message of at least 64 characters  [in quantities of 8 characters] and repeat the process of modifying 1-17 for the first 8;  modifying by 17 -1 for next 8,  and so on. Make your own message.  After the message is coded, decoding should also be done, to restore the original message.  You may want to change the lower case and upper case transitions as well.

```
   Example:  Original Message           A     B     C    D. …..
                     Normal ASCII      65    66    67   68   ….
                     Prime Numbers      1     2     3    5   ….          
                     Enhanced ASCII    66    68    70   73 ….
                     Coded Message      B     D     F    I   ……
```

I'm having trouble printing out the prime numbers without messing up the code afterwards such as the encoded and decoded ASCII codes and the encoded and decoded codes. This is my code so far: 
If you could help me somehow that would be great! I would really appreciate it, thank you.

```
size_t x;
int i, c;

i = 1;
c = 0;

char text[65];
int s[8] = {1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17};

printf("Enter a line of text: "); // prompts user to enter text
fgets(text, 65, stdin); // reads input from user
printf("\nOriginal Message: ");
for(x = 0; x < strlen(text); ++x) // for loop to print original message
{
    printf("%c", text[x]);
} // end for

// ASCII Code
printf("\nASCII Code: ");
for(x = 0; x < strlen(text) - 1; ++x)
{
    printf("%d ", text[x]);
}

// prime numbers
// my issue is here
printf("\n\nPrime Numbers: ");
for(x = 0; x <= 8 ; ++x)
{
    if(c == 0)
    {
        if(i == 1)
        {
            printf("1 ");
            ++i;
        }
        else if(i == 2)
        {
            printf("2 ");
            ++i;
        }
        else if(i == 3)
        {
            printf("3 ");
            ++i;
        }
        else if(i == 4)
        {
            printf("5 ");
            ++i;
        }
        else if(i == 5)
        {
            printf("7 ");
            ++i;
        }
        else if(i == 6)
        {
            printf("11 ");
            ++i;
        }
        else if(i == 7)
        {
            printf("13 ");
            ++i;
        }
        else if(i == 8)
        {
            printf("17 ");
            ++c;
            ++x;
        }
    }
    if(c == 1)
    {
        if(i == 8)
        {
            printf("17 ");
            --i;
        }
        else if(i == 7)
        {
            printf("13 ");
            --i;
        }
        else if(i == 6)
        {
            printf("11 ");
            --i;
        }
        else if(i == 5)
        {
            printf("7 ");
            --i;
        }
        else if(i == 4)
        {
            printf("5 ");
            --i;
        }
        else if(i == 3)
        {
            printf("3 ");
            --i;
        }
        else if(i == 2)
        {
            printf("2 ");
            --i;
        }
        else if(i == 1)
        {
            printf("1 ");
            --c;
        }
    } // end outer if
} // issue ends here


for(x = 0; x < strlen(text) - 1; ++x)
{
    if(c == 0) // outer if statement increasing
    {
        if(i == 1) // inner if statement
        {
            text[x] = text[x] + 1;
            ++i;
        }
        else if (i == 2)
        {
            text[x] = text[x] + 2;
            ++i;
        }
        else if (i == 3)
        {
            text[x] = text[x] + 3;
            ++i;
        }
        else if(i == 4)
        {
            text[x] = text[x] + 5;
            ++i;
        }
        else if(i == 5)
        {
            text[x] = text[x] + 7;
            ++i;
        }
        else if(i == 6)
        {
            text[x] = text[x] + 11;
            ++i;
        }
        else if(i == 7)
        {
            text[x] = text[x] + 13;
            ++i;
        }
        else if(i == 8)
        {
            text[x] = text[x] + 17;
            ++c;
            ++x;
        } // end if statement
    } // end outer if statement
    if(c == 1) // outer if statement decreasing
    {
        if(i == 8)
        {
            text[x] = text[x] + 17;
            --i;
        }
        else if(i == 7)
        {
            text[x] = text[x] + 13;
            --i;
        }
        else if(i == 6)
        {
            text[x] = text[x] + 11;
            --i;
        }
        else if(i == 5)
        {
            text[x] = text[x] + 7;
            --i;
        }
        else if(i == 4)
        {
            text[x] = text[x] + 5;
            --i;
        }
        else if(i == 3)
        {
            text[x] = text[x] + 3;
            --i;
        }
        else if(i == 2)
        {
            text[x] = text[x] + 2;
            --i;
        }
        else if(i == 1)
        {
            text[x] = text[x] + 1;
            --c;
        }
    } // end outer if
} // end for
printf("\n\nEncrypted Message: ");
for(x = 0; x <= strlen(text) - 1; ++x)
{
   printf("%c", text[x]);
}

printf("\nEncrypted ASCII: ");
for(x = 0; x < strlen(text) - 1; x++)
{
    printf("%d ", text[x]);
}

c = 0;
i = 1;

for(x = 0; x < strlen(text) - 1; ++x)
{
    if(c == 0)
    {
        if(i == 1)
        {
            text[x] = text[x] - 1;
            ++i;
        }
        else if(i == 2)
        {
            text[x] = text[x] - 2;
            ++i;
        }
        else if(i == 3)
        {
            text[x] = text[x] - 3;
            ++i;
        }
        else if(i == 4)
        {
            text[x] = text[x] - 5;
            ++i;
        }
        else if(i == 5)
        {
            text[x] = text[x] - 7;
            ++i;
        }
        else if(i == 6)
        {
            text[x] = text[x] - 11;
            ++i;
        }
        else if(i == 7)
        {
            text[x] = text[x] - 13;
            ++i;
        }
        else if(i == 8)
        {
            text[x] = text[x] - 17;
            ++c;
            ++x;
        } // end if statement
    } // end outer if statement
    if(c == 1)
    {
        if(i == 8)
        {
            text[x] = text[x] - 17;
            --i;
        }
        else if(i == 7)
        {
            text[x] = text[x] - 13;
            --i;
        }
        else if(i == 6)
        {
            text[x] = text[x] - 11;
            --i;
        }
        else if(i == 5)
        {
            text[x] = text[x] - 7;
            --i;
        }
        else if(i == 4)
        {
            text[x] = text[x] - 5;
            --i;
        }
        else if(i == 3)
        {
            text[x] = text[x] - 3;
            --i;
        }
        else if(i == 2)
        {
            text[x] = text[x] - 2;
            --i;
        }
        else if(i == 1)
        {
            text[x] = text[x] - 1;
            --c;
        } // end inner if statements
    } // end outer if statements
} // end for

printf("\n\nDecrypted Message: ");
for(x = 0; x < strlen(text); ++x)
{
    printf("%c", text[x]);
}

printf("\nDecrypted ASCII: ");
for(x = 0; x < strlen(text) - 1; ++x)
{
    printf("%d ", text[x]);
}
```

puts(" ");
} // end main

Comment: Can you describe, with output examples, where your program goes wrong? Just dumping a big pile of code here and asking to please find the bug, is a bit rude.

Comment: I edited my post and specified where the problem is using comments, basically I am trying to print out the prime numbers but I can't because it messes up the rest of my code and I wanted to know if there's an alternate way of printing out the prime numbers so it doesn't mess it up? For example if the user inputs "engineering" it has to come out as "1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 17, 15, 13". It increases up till 17 for every 8 characters and then decreases for the next 8. But I've been trying to work around this and it keeps on messing up my decryption and encryption codes that are afterwards.

Comment: Oh! And I would post up a photo of the output but it doesn't let me :/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to modify ASCII with prime numbers C program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30831331/how-to-modify-ascii-with-prime-numbers-c-program)

Answer (score 0):

Characters are represented by numbers. For example, for ASCII, `z` is represented by the number 122. If you add something to that value then you get a new value (e.g. `122 + 17 = 139`). That new value may not be valid ASCII (e.g. 128 or larger), and might be a control code (e.g. 127 is the "delete" control character).

Because the values may no longer represent valid characters, you can't print them as characters. You need to print them as values (e.g. `for(x = 0; text[x] != 0; x++) { printf("%d ", text[x]); }`).

Worse, for "signed char", the addition can cause overflow, which is undefined behaviour in C. You'd need to use a different data type (e.g. `unsigned char` or `uint8_t`) to ensure the code has defined/expected behaviour.

Also note that your long chain of "if .. else if ... else if" statements should be a "switch()" with cases; more like this:

```
    switch(i) {
        case 1:
            text[x] = text[x] + 1;
            ++i;
            break;
        case 2:
            text[x] = text[x] + 2;
            ++i;
            break;
        ...
    }
```

However; by using `int s[16] = {1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 17, 13, 11, 7, 5, 3, 2, 1};` you'd be able replace many lines of similar code with something like this:

```
    for(x = 0; text[x] != 0; x++) {
        text[x] += s[x % 16]);
    }
```